# Hexapod Servo Controller Issue - Adafruit PCA9685 16Channel

Tags: raspberry-pi, robots.txt, robotics, adafruit, servo

I'm creating an Hexapod using a Raspberry Pi 3, 2 X [16 Channel Adafruit PCA9685 servo controller](https://www.adafruit.com/product/815) chained, and multiple [Tower Pro MG995](http://www.towerpro.com.tw/product/mg995/) servos for the limbs.

**Issue that I've encountered is that when connecting multiple Servos to the controller and then to the power supply, most of the servos start to move on their own without me running any code or commands.**

This issue does not occur when I test individual servos or at most 3 at the same time.

I'm currently using a 5V 2.5A power supply and have tested a set of 4 AA battery pack 1.5V alkaline with a similar result.

As a guideline I'm following [this](https://github.com/mithi/hexy) template.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to find a solution, by swapping the PSU for a **5V 4A**, and **capacitors** for the servo controllers for an **2200uf 16V and 1000uf 16V**, since the current/power draw of the servos was to high causing incompatibility with the previous PSU and low tier capacitors that created constant interference.